# sql: Сортировка по дате

Tags: sql

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите пожалуйста как мне отсортировать все записи по дате, но не только по возрастанию, но и начиная от сегодня, например:

6 декабря (ближайшая дата)

12 декабря

3 января

6 июня

1 декабря

Другой пример:

Например сегодня 6 июня

6 июня

1 декабря

6 декабря

12 декабря

3 января

Часть решения у меня уже есть:

```
SELECT * FROM db ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(begin, '%m%d')
```

используя where не вариант, т.к надо выводить все записи.

Comment: Почему 1 декабря в примере стоит на последнем месте?

Comment: Потому что по сути у нас есть  записи за весь год от 1го января и до 31 декабря. и нам нужно их отсортировать так, что бы выводились все даты которые ближе к сегодняшней и шли по порядку) т.е получается этакий круг.

Comment: И что должно быть в сортировке с записями, которые ДО текущей даты ? Как нибудь пример поправьте, например текущую дату возьмите за июль и несколько дат ДО и ПОСЛЕ текущей

Comment: И мне, как пользователю, например, совершенно непонятно будет почему я должен искать довольно близкую дату 1 декабря где то в конце списка. Я бы еще понял если бы это было 1 декабря следующего года, но года тут нет

Comment: Указал доп. пример.
Это надо для вывода ближайших события, но по порядку.
Пользователю будет не очень интересно смотреть какие события были до сегодня, а если и будет интересно, то он воспользуется фильтром, но фильтр это уже совсем другая тема :)

Comment: @Zeloras А в вашем втором примере 1 мая после 3 января или до 1 декабря ?

Comment: И диалект SQL (СУБД) укажите, тут без функций не обойтись, а у каждой базы данных функции разные и вообще пути решения могут быть раными

Comment: @Mike После 1 декабря, месяца тоже по порядку идут как и даты

Comment: @Zeloras после 1 декабря, это значит - перед 6 декабря ? тогда вообще не понимаю почему

Comment: >>mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.46, for FreeBSD10.1

Видимо вас не понял до конца, вот как бы это выглядело во втором примере:

6 июня

1 декабря

6 декабря

12 декабря

3 января

1 мая

Comment: @Zeloras если честно - не понимаю, чем вас не устраивает сортировка просто по begin. Если надо при этом показать только события в будущем - то это не вопрос сортировки

Comment: @PashaPash Меня полностью устраивает, но по задачке надо сделать помимо обычно сортировки по дате, сортировку и по ближайшей записи, до этого я делал вариант с where где выводились действительно ближайшие записи, но остальных записей небыло, этот вариант не устроил, сказали что надо по порядку и по ближайшей дате, т.к все события повторяются.

Comment: @Zeloras покажите исходные данные. Каких "остальных" записей не было? Записей в прошлом?

Comment: @PashaPash Вас интересует 440 записей в базе или формат полей?
begin  Y-m-d (Год может быть и 2003 и 2020)

Comment: @Zeloras Я там написал ответ, мне кажется это именно то что вам нужно, как бы странно не выглядели требования заказчика. Я таких заказчиков стараюсь переубеждать, потому как это просто неудобно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select B.* from
 (
  select db.*,
         DATE_FORMAT(begin, '%m%d') - DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%m%d') as DIFF
    from db
 ) B
 ORDER BY (CASE WHEN diff<0 THEN 20000+diff ELSE DIFF END)
```

В принципе можно без подзапроса, но мне не нравится выписывать длиннющие строки с `date_format`. Но основная идея: получаем число, "расстояние" от текущей даты до тестируемой и если оно меньше 0 (Дата *до* текущей) то увеличиваем "расстояние" так, что бы оно оказалось после всех дат, которые *после*

Comment: кланяюсь в ноги! Огромное спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна обычная сортировка по дате + фильтр, чтобы показать события в будщем

```
SELECT * FROM db 
WHERE begin > NOW()
ORDER BY begin
```

Если при этом не нужно выводить год - решайте это при выводе значения, а не в сортировке.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас опробую этот пример но убирая год из условия)

Comment: Ммм...Близко к этому, но выводит не все записи
Вот запрос

SELECT * FROM db WHERE DATE_FORMAT(begin, '%m%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m%d') ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(begin, '%m%d')